# Hybrid Application closes without giving any error in logcat while uploading images

Tags: javascript, android, image, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to upload a lot of images to the server say nearly 100 images each of size 300 kb. When I try to upload the image, some of the images about 15-18 images gets synced to the server but then the application closes(just exists) without any app crash message or error in logcat.

Is this a memory issue. May be I am not freeing up the memory used by individual images.

Here is my code for syncing image

```
    function SyncImage(ImageName, TryCount)
{
  var basicpath = localStorage.getItem('ImagePath');

    var Filename = Imagename;
    var src = basicpath + Filename + "?" + new Date().getTime();
  //  var src = "image.jpg";

    var myCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

    var img1 = document.createElement('img');


    img1.onload = function()
    {
        var imgwidth = img1.width;
        var imgheight = img1.height;

        myCanvas.width = imgwidth;
        myCanvas.height = imgheight;

        context.drawImage(img1,10,10,imgwidth,imgheight);
        //console.log("Image Ready");
      //  alert("Image Ready");

        var myurl = myCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

        urlimage = Filename + myurl;


       // console.log("contacting server");
      //  alert("contacting server");

        var nRequest =  new XMLHttpRequest();
        nRequest.open("POST", dbstatements.domain_address+"api/upload_image.php", true);
        nRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        nRequest.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent)
        {
            if (nRequest.readyState == 4)
            {
                if (nRequest.status == 200)
                {
                  // console.log(Filename);
                  // alert("uploaded");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    SyncImage(ImageName, Number(TryCount+1));
                }
            }
        };
        nRequest.send(urlimage);


           img1.src = " ";
           img1 = null;

    }

    img1.src = src;

}
```

This is my logcat output

```
07-05 17:28:13.317 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime:     [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
07-05 17:28:13.318 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
07-05 17:28:19.010 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:42] restartInput
07-05 17:28:19.014 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:50] showSoftInput
07-05 17:28:19.027 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:77] updateSelection: SEL [0, 0], COM [-1, -1]
07-05 17:28:19.085 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:89] updateCursorAnchorInfo
07-05 17:28:19.732 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:89] updateCursorAnchorInfo
07-05 17:28:53.402 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:77] updateSelection: SEL [3, 3], COM [-1, -1]
07-05 17:28:53.448 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:89] updateCursorAnchorInfo
07-05 17:28:53.513 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:77] updateSelection: SEL [3, 3], COM [0, 3]
07-05 17:28:53.514 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:77] updateSelection: SEL [3, 3], COM [0, 3]
07-05 17:28:53.549 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:89] updateCursorAnchorInfo
07-05 17:28:53.806 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:42] restartInput
07-05 17:28:53.810 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:77] updateSelection: SEL [3, 3], COM [-1, -1]
07-05 17:28:53.811 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:77] updateSelection: SEL [3, 3], COM [-1, -1]
07-05 17:28:53.814 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:89] updateCursorAnchorInfo
07-05 17:28:53.849 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:42] restartInput
07-05 17:28:53.861 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:42] restartInput
07-05 17:28:53.865 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:50] showSoftInput
07-05 17:28:53.868 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:77] updateSelection: SEL [0, 0], COM [-1, -1]
07-05 17:28:53.869 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-05 17:28:53.878 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-05 17:28:53.880 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-05 17:28:53.937 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:89] updateCursorAnchorInfo
07-05 17:28:54.197 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:89] updateCursorAnchorInfo
07-05 17:28:54.851 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:77] updateSelection: SEL [1, 1], COM [-1, -1]
07-05 17:28:54.916 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:89] updateCursorAnchorInfo
07-05 17:28:55.209 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:77] updateSelection: SEL [2, 2], COM [-1, -1]
07-05 17:28:55.263 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:89] updateCursorAnchorInfo
07-05 17:28:55.628 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:77] updateSelection: SEL [3, 3], COM [-1, -1]
07-05 17:28:55.668 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:89] updateCursorAnchorInfo
07-05 17:28:56.135 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
07-05 17:28:56.136 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
07-05 17:28:56.139 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:42] restartInput
07-05 17:28:56.189 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 12213
07-05 17:28:58.693 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 12213
07-05 17:28:58.698 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
07-05 17:28:58.698 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
07-05 17:29:30.407 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
07-05 17:29:30.407 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
07-05 17:29:30.456 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
07-05 17:29:30.457 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
07-05 17:29:31.383 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
07-05 17:29:31.384 12213-12213/com.example.ac046137.csm D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you use phonegap/cordova engine?

I recommend you to use file transfer plugin. Because upload with native code is more effective.

The webview has limited memory.

Comment: No I use only webview. Our requirement was such that I couldn't use phonegap/cordova.  Is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: I worked with hybrid application and I always had this problem (memory). Try make a own native code for send files.

Comment: So is there no way I can clear the webview memory once each image request is sent to server....

Comment: As far as i know, no. Webview is very limited. For explore all resources is need native code.

Comment: Can I run a sheduler to clear webview cache every few seconds ?

Comment: With native code it's posible, but inside webview not.

Comment: Is there any hack to not get this issue??